# How to structure date attribute inside Regular dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssas

Let's say it's a **Customer** Dimension with a *CustomerBirthday* field that is a date.

I currently have this field available as part of the **Customer** dimension, but it's just treated as a text field because it's an attribute of customer. Users cannot use this field like they can with date fields that are using the date dimension.

Other than including *CustomerBirthday* as a key inside my fact table and using the date dimension that way, how would I go about using *CustomerBirthday* as a date inside the **Customer** dimension?

Even setting the attribute to 'Date' type in the dimension properties in VS results in the warning

> 'The Attribute type is set to Date which is not compatible with the
> 'Regular' dimension type'

(This is in MultiDimensional)

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a CustomerBirthdateDateId field in the model that converts the date into an Integer so that you can associate the SK with the Date dimension?

e.g. 1975-04-03 would become 19750403

Comment: Yeah that would be the alternative -- including a key at the fact level. But I was just interested in treating the CustomerBirthday as a date within the customer dimension, rather than pulling it out of the customer dimension into its own date dimension